# apache cannot run any php

Tags: php, apache

I've installed an apache server on my raspberry pi and everything seems to be running fine unless I try to serve php.

```
/var/www/html/index.html serves fine
/var/www/html/foo/index/index.html serves fines
```

But if I add index.php, let's say :

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

I get **403 -Forbbiden** by accessing /var/www/html but I can still access /var/www/html/foo/index.html (DirectoryIndex set to .php .html .htm).

And if I run `$php index.php` : hello world

**So, it does can serves .html, it can run .php but it cannot serve .php.**

How can I fix this ? I found many solutions but none worked for me.

Note : 
I access the sites from the LAN.
Server OS (uname -a) : Linux raspbian-AH 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

As stated in the comments, we could easily deduce module is not loaded but I here it is :

```
pi@raspbian-AH:/etc/apache2/mods-available $ cat php5.conf 
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
# 
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

and the php5.load:

```
pi@raspbian-AH:/etc/apache2/mods-available $ cat php5.load
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add the PHP module to `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: That file doesn't exist on my filesystem (test with find) but I suppose /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is the name for mine?

Comment: What particular distribution of linux are you using?

Comment: Do you have `libapache2-mod-php5` installed? Are the permissions for `index.php` correct so that www-data has read access?

Comment: Yes but just in case I purged it along with php5 and apache2 and reinstalled them. It works fine now.
I must have messed up with there settings at some point.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dan08, I found out my set up was messed up is some way. So rather than to pinpoint the problem I purged everything and install it anew. There wasn't anything to save anyway.

So the solution was :

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```